# Generic type in Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs

I am trying to follow [flux async](https://github.com/facebook/flux/tree/master/examples/flux-async) example. During which I came across the following [code](https://github.com/facebook/flux/blob/master/examples/flux-async/src/load_object/LoadObjectMap.js):

```
class LoadObjectMap<K, V>
```

I am having tough time understanding from which library is the generics in the above code supported. I Googled but I wasn't able to find any documentation. Any link to the document or any explanation of what is going on would be helpful

Answer (score 4):

This is JavaScript with [flow](https://flow.org/). Flow is a static type checker for JavaScript.

Basically, "flow" provides type additional syntax for normal JavaScript code. After you write your JavaScript with flow type syntax you can use [flow-cli](https://flow.org/en/docs/cli/) tool to check your code against flow type checker for any type errors. However, since JavaScript engines can't understand flow syntax you have to use ["Strip flow types transform"](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-flow-strip-types/) babel plugin or ["flow-remove-types"](https://flow.org/en/docs/tools/flow-remove-types/) CLI tool to remove type syntax and convert the code to normal JavaScript.

The syntax you have mentioned use [generic types](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/generics/) comes with flow.